# Typescript server in docker compose container not hearing requests from host

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a straightforward docker compose setup, running an api server (fastify + typescript) and a database (postgres).

### The Problem

I cannot curl from my host machine into the api container. I've spent all day debugging this.

- I've confirmed my server is running - inside the container, curl localhost:8080 works well.
- I've connected to my database from the host machine, outside the container.
- I've connected to my database from the api container
- I've run `npx http-server` instead of my full api server, and I can access this server from outside the container

My only theory is that my startup command (copied from a sample ts+fastify repo) is causing problems somehow. `"tsnd -r tsconfig-paths/register --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child src/index.ts"`

### The Question

What is it about my typescript server that results in an inability to access the container's server from the host?

compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://user:password@db:5432/cv3
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  db:
    image: postgres:14.10
    container_name: postgres-cv3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: cv3
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/db_dump/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

Comment: Sounds like your IP is listening on localhost rather than every interface, i.e. `0.0.0.0` as it should.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for the reply. Which IP are you referring to - the api container? Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Wow, you have saved my weekend. I can set the host in my fastify server.listen() call to "::" and it works!